# MySql (RDS Amazon aws) no conecta desde cualquier sitio, solo mi pc

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, amazon, amazon-rds

Tengo un login hecho en c#, el cual conecta con una base de datos, la base de datos es de Amazon Aws, y conecta perfectamente, al menos desde mi IP, El problema esta en que no es accesible desde cualquier ordenador con diferente IP.

Soy consciente de que es la configuración del RDS de amazon aws, pero no tengo ni la menor idea de qué debería cambiar para que la base de datos sea accesible desde cualquier sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca compartas tu endpoint por internet podría ser peligroso!.

En "**security Groups**" debes agregar tu ip, evita abrir el puerto para todo mundo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]